# Как имитировать нажатие на опцию выпадающего списка?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно имитировать нажатие на определенную опцию выпадающего списка?

Например, есть кнопки:

```
<a class="but-1">butt</a>
<a class="but-2">butt</a>
```

И список:

```
<select>
    <option value="val1">value1</option>
    <option value="val2">value2</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `.but-1` имитировалось нажатие, как мышкой на опцию `val1`?

Comment: Вам нужно воспроизвести именно нажатие? или просто выбрать `val1` в списке, как если бы оно было выбрано вручную?

Comment: Как если бы было выбрано вручную, мышкой. Т.е. нажал на список, выпали элементы, мышкой кликнул на опцию. как-то так

Comment: вы это хотите получить? - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vun3j8Lp/

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это можно так:

1. добавим к кнопке атрибут `data-select`, который будет содержать `value` пункта для выбора;
2. вешаем обработчик события на блок с кнопками;
3. в обработчике смотрим, есть ли у элемента вызвавшего его атрибут `data-select`, если есть, то выбираем нужный пункт в выпадающем списке;
4. вызываем событие `change`.

Полный пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyaywt56/1/):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-group')[0].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var elem = evt.target;
    if (elem.hasAttribute('data-select')) {
        document.getElementById('select').value = elem.getAttribute('data-select');

        var elem = document.getElementById('select');
        var event = new Event('change');
        elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}, false);
```

При выставлении "вручную", после изменения значения, читайте поля `.value` в `select`'е, происходит событие `change`. Поэтому, после программного выбора нужного элемента в списке, надо вызвать это событие. Я описал вариант решения на чистом JS, все это легко можно переписать при помощи jQuery, тогда событие будет вызываться так:

```
$(select).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

В более менее организованном виде оно выглядит так.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btns').on('click', 'a[data-option]', function() {
    option = $(this).data('option');
    $('.select option[value="' + option + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    return false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btns">
  <a href="#" data-option="value1">Кнопка 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-option="value2">Кнопка 2</a>
</div>

<select class="select">
  <option value="">Выбери меня</option>
  <option value="value1">Выбор 1</option>
  <option value="value2">Выбор 2</option>
</select>
```

В вашем случае вам может хватить для понимания и строки

```
 $('.select option[value="' + option + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: да, работает, спасибо. но меняется только значении в селекте. у меня срабатывает функция при "живом" нажатии на опцию, а если использовать решение "неживого" выбора, функция не срабатывает

Comment: Если честно, я не понимаю. что значит "не живой" выбор?